# Shared DLL - dependencies

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I have a DLL which is shared between several projects. This contains some common custom controls and the like. Now inside the dll project i use log4net to log any issues thrown by these controls.

This however means i need to include log4net in all my other projects or i get a cannot resolve dependency error. Adding log4net is not a big issue i use it in the other projects.

However, i can't help but feel this is something that shouldn't be done?
or is there a solution other than having to add the dependency to any project using my DLL?

Comment: I think setting Copy Local to True on the DLL reference will cause it to be output to any project that references that particular project, saving you from adding the reference to each individual project.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea upon which inclusion of dependencies happen is as follows -- Any project includes only those dependencies which are explicitly used within some code.

To elaborate, suppose that in a project P, you have assemblies A1, A2. And this assembly A1 inturn uses assembly A2 and A1 is referenced in P and used in some parts of the code. Now if we see, we have both A1 and A2 as a part of P. But when we include the reference to project P into some other project Q, then we do not have A2 available in Q because P does not have any explicit code using A2 within it.

That is why you require to include the reference explicitly even though it is a part of a common member that is being referenced.

Hope this helps.